# INNER JOIN with ORDER BY and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, inner-join

Table: pm_productos
Fields: prod_ID, prov_prod_nif, prod_fechafactura, prod_numerofactura, prod_totalproducto

---

Table: pm_proveedores
Fields: prov_ID, prov_nif, prov_nombre, etc...

My query is:

```
$query = "SELECT pm_productos.*, pp.prov_nombre FROM pm_productos INNER JOIN 
pm_proveedores pp ON pp.prov_nif = pm_productos.prov_prod_nif 
WHERE prod_nombreproducto like '%$search%' LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage" ;
```

My output table is:

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>
   <td>",$row[1],"</td>
   <td>",$row[10],"</td>
   <td>",date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row[2])),"
       <td><a href='fact_view.php?roll=".$row[3]."'>".$row[3]."</a></td>
   <td>",$row[4],"</td>
   <td>",$row[5],"</td>
   <td align=center>",$row[6],"</td>
   <td align=right>",$row[7],"</td>
   <td align=right>",$row[8],"</td>
   <td align=right>",$row[9],"</td>
}
```

The code works fine, but I've 2 questions:

1. Page productos_view.php - How to "ORDER BY prod_fechafactura" in this INNER JOIN? (prod_fechafactura is a date field).
2. Page facturas_view.php - With the same INNER JOIN, how to select between two dates (in the field prod_fechafactura), and then display in the table the SUM of prod_totalproducto GROUP BY prod_numerofactura for each provider (prov_nif and prov_nombre)? (If no dates are selected display all records ordered by prod_fechafactura, as this:

prov_nif, prov_nombre, prod_fechafactura, prod_numerofactura, SUM of prod_totalproducto

Answer (score 0):

This is for the first one : to order by `prod_fechafactura`

```
    $query = "SELECT pm_productos.*, pp.prov_nombre FROM pm_productos INNER JOIN 
    pm_proveedores pp ON pp.prov_nif = pm_productos.prov_prod_nif 
    WHERE prod_nombreproducto like '%$search%' LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage 
    ORDER BY prod_fechafactura" ;
```

And this is for the second one: to sum prod_totalproducto

```
    $query = "SELECT PP.prov_nif, pp.prov_nombre, SUM(prod_totalproducto)
    FROM pm_productos INNER JOIN 
    pm_proveedores pp ON pp.prov_nif = pm_productos.prov_prod_nif 
    WHERE prod_nombreproducto like '%$search%'
    AND prod_fechafactura BETWEEN 'start date' AND 'end date' 
    GROUP BY prov_nif,prov_nombre
    LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage" ;
```